# Problems opening modal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm having some troubles trying to make this modal work. I have a flatlist with a lot of data inside and each item should be clickable to open a modal. Right now when im clicking the item in the flatlist nothing happens. What am I missing?

..........................................................................................................................................................................................................

```
export default function Home() {
const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);

  renderItem = ({ item, index }) => {
    return (
      <View>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={{
            margin: 15,
            padding: 10,
            borderRadius: 10,
          }}
          onPress={() => getItem(item)}>
          <Text style={{ color: colors.text, fontWeight: '700' }}>
            {item.name}
          </Text>
          <Text style={{ color: colors.text }}>{item.company}</Text>
          <Text style={{ color: colors.text }}>{item.info}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  };

  const getItem = (item) => {
    return (
      <Modal
        hardwareAccelerated={true}
        animationType="slide"
        visible={modalVisible}>
        <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#fff' }}>
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => {
              setModalVisible(!modalVisible);
            }}></TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </Modal>
    );
  };

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: colors.background }}>
      <View
        style={{
          flexDirection: 'row',
          justifyContent: 'center',
          alignItems: 'center',
          padding: 19,
        }}>
        <TextInput
          style={[
            {
              flex: 1,
              backgroundColor: '#fff',
              borderRadius: 10,
              shadowColor: '#888888',
              shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 1 },
              shadowOpacity: 0.8,
              shadowRadius: 2,
              elevation: 3,
            },
          ]}
          placeholder="Sök"
          placeholderTextColor="#000"
          onChangeText={(text) => setSearch(text)}
          value={search}
        />
      </View>
      <View>
        <FlatList
          data={filteredDataSource}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
          initialNumToRender={5}
          showsVerticalScrollIndicator={true}
          renderItem={renderItem}
          style={{ height: 475 }}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: You're not setting the `modalVisible state`

Comment: @TaghiKhavari would you mind showing code? I have looked at the docs, still it doesn't open. I tried using this onPress={() => {
          setModalVisible(true);
        }}

Answer (score 0):

You did not change the visible state of your modal in your onPress function.

In your onPress function for the FlatList item, add setModalVisible(true) before getItem(item)

Comment: tried this, but it doesn't work 

onPress={() => {
            setModalVisible(true);
            getItem(item);
          }}

Comment: Oh, also, your modal should be a child of the main view. So instead of returning the modal on click, place it right before the FlatList as they'd both be children of the main view component that way. It should work fine.

Comment: So instead of returning the modal on click, place it right before the FlatList as they'd both be children of the main view component that way. This was the issue and it's now working.